# Why is there an offset in the background position of an image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

I want to arrange three image panels, each with the same background image, side by side to give the impression that it is a single image.
In this raw version, all dimensions are fixed. The frame is 900 pixels wide and each panel is 300 pixels wide.
For the optical illusion, the positions of the background image are each close-fitted.
But it does not work. There is a offset that I can't explain. The offset is 11 pixels wide.
Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks in advance

**This is how it looks**
[image]
**The Source**

```
<main class="frame">
  <div class="panel panel--one"></div>
  <div class="panel panel--two"></div>
  <div class="panel panel--three"></div>
</main>
```

**The styles**
Besides the css posted here, I use a reset from meyerweb.com.

```
.frame {
    background-color: #0080e2;
    background-size: 900px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("../images/image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.panel--two {
  background-position: -300px;
}

.panel--three {
  background-position: -600px;
}
```

Comment: Can you upload and share the original image? Seems to work fine with no border on a random image I chose

Comment: This is the original image (i edited it to 900 pixel width): https://unsplash.com/photos/FSbgF7PpUio

Comment: So it is the border to the right is it? From the above image it was not clear if the border was the black around the image or the lighter strip of blue to the right...

Comment: I named it border but basically it is an offset. Sorry.

Comment: Did you Crop the image ? The actual size is 1332 x 749 so the 900 will be 506.08, is not 900 x 500 this can cause the offset. Try to remove the "width:500px;" from the frame

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why don't you apply the background to the .frame container ?

Comment: @Oliver glad to help

Answer (score 1):

This is due to body tag. Body tag has margin of 8px. You can just put this in your css.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, besides the css posted here, I use a reset from meyerweb.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to to add "border: 0px" , some browsers show a default border. Do you see the border even when you are not in the "Inspect mode" ?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas_krk, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Oliver, can you try applying `border:0` to `body` ? In the computed style you would notice a 8px value for it.

Comment: @Philippe - I think you mean the margin of 8px?
I have tried it, your hint leads unfortunately to no result